# How do I test with multiple input combinations?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a piece of code that I need to test, which is layered in three parts:

- `Web API Controller`
- `Persistence/Logic Layer`
- `System calls for persistence`

It's the basic `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` call system.
For instance, in the controller I have the `GetAll` method which calls into a `Get` in the second layer, which in turn calls either some `Sql database` method either another `web api` method.

The scenarios:
Mock the `second layer` and call the `controller`.
Mock the `system calls` and call the `second layer`.
Mock the `system calls` and call the `controller`.

For each scenario, I have multiple test inputs, for each method in the `controller/second` layer.

What would be the best way to do it? I want to have as little as possible code duplication.

I can use a `datasource attribute` on my test and have for each test a layer value that would select the type of mocking that I would to do, and for each layer value, I would add test data(input parameters). But that test data would be common for all layer values, which would mean that I would have to duplicate it for each layer value. Also I would have the same layer values for all methods in the `controller/persistence` layer, which again would be a duplicate.

I would like to factor out in some way the layer values, which would be common for all tests(think of class level values) and also have specific input values for each method in the `controller`(method level). And for each method then, I would have a test in which I would do some sort of a cross product in between the general layer values and the specific method input values.
How could I achieve that?

Thanks,
Ciprian.

Comment: Sure you can test each layer isolated, but if you do so, you still dont know if the are working in combination without mocks. I really like the way to set up system tests. That means you test the whole system. As one. Then you have tested all three layers at once. I dont know what you think about this solution but i like it.
Maybe the better pace for you question is [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: From my point of view, it does make sense to do layer testing, because most of the time it is hard to write usecases to execute all layer interface logic from the very top layer. But I agree to your point, that just because all layer tests are working the system is working properly